# PHP Matching the output of 2 codes

Tags: php

I need to match the result format of 2 code:

I need to get the output/format of this:

```
$event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;  // $event_day
```

match this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Full code:

```
$query = "
  SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date 
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' 
    AND date BETWEEN '$year-$month-1' AND '" . date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1")) . "' 
    AND active = 1";
```

My problem is that $event_day is only displaying events for: October, November and December.

I had a similar problem with this code below:

```
$query = "
  SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date 
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' 
    AND date LIKE '$year-$month%' 
    AND active = 1";
```

and it was fixed with this code:

```
$query = "
  SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date 
  FROM table 
  WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' 
    AND date BETWEEN '$year-$month-1' AND '" . date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1")) . "' 
    AND active = 1";
```

Anyone know how I could sort this out?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question... What exactly is the problem? The format? Or that you don't get the expected results from the DB? What type is the `date`-field in your table of? And what exactly are you trying to achieve? Get all events for the current month?

Comment: For example: This query would only show events dates for Oct, Nov and Dec. $query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM table WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date LIKE '$year-$month%' AND active = 1";  --- It was fixed by changing the code to this: $query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d') AS date FROM table WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' AND date BETWEEN '$year-$month-1' AND '" . date("Y-m-t", strtotime("$year-$month-1")) . "' AND active = 1";

Comment: .... So the above now works BUT now this: $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;  ...is only displaying Oct, Nov and Dec events ... so same issue?

Comment: So what is is supposed to display instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to match dates in a SQL query, which is what you look like you're after, you can just pass the date as a string with a `#` on each end. This will tell SQL to parse the string as a date and the format you give it in is not really important. The exception to this is it can get confused between US/EU date formats like dd/mm/yyyy vs mm/dd/yyyy.

```
$query = "SELECT title, DATE_FORMAT(myDate,'%Y-%m-%d') AS formattedDate 
          FROM table 
          WHERE user_id = '$session_user_id' 
          AND (myDate BETWEEN #$year-$month-1# AND #$year-$month-1#) 
          AND active = 1";
```

This format should work but your query is select records that fall between the same date so you'll only get records that are actually on that date. You might as well just use `WHERE date = #$year-$month-1#`

**edit**: this assumes your date field datatype is correctly set up in the database as a date/time.

**edit2**: "date" is often a reserved word in databases and shouldn't really be used for field names and variables. See edited code above.

In addition I would suggest using php to format the date using the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function rather than format it in the query. This allows more flexibility to actually use the date in your script.

Comment: Sorry, this is not returning any results. This other query is actually getting the records it's this: $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day; if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
 foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
    $calendar.= '<div class="event"><a href="cal_popup.php?title='.$event['title'].'" target="blank" title="'.$event['title'].'">'.$event['title'].'</a></div>';
}  ...that's not catching and displaying them apart from Oct, Nov and Dec. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's difficult to know what your problem is without knowing what the overall goal of this code is. I can see you're trying to query a database using php variables but that's about the extent